# Error setting an array element with a sequence, when using Pandas, astype (float)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have large dataset which i am reading from text file and I want to perform an operation on it. I use

```
T[fields[0:-1]]=T[fields[0:-1]].astype(float)
```

to be sure that all the values are float. I get the Error setting an array element with a sequence on one the columns. I changed `T.replace('NaN', np.nan)` the NaN to nan but still the same issue.  I used

```
dtypeCount =[T.iloc[:,i].apply(type).value_counts() for i in range(T.shape[1])]
```

to determine the type of the data on that column and this is the results

```
 Name: PD_PRESSURE, dtype: int64, <class 'NoneType'>    3676479
 <class 'float'>        192217
```

Due to size of the dataset I can't figure out where this coming from. Any thought on how I can solve this or how how I can find what is causing this?

Thanks in advance.

---

Update: Full Error message

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-fa0a78194654> in <module>()
    162     if Aggregate_Flag==1:
    163         # This line make sure that all the data are defined as float
--> 164         T[fields[0:-1]]=T[fields[0:-1]].astype(float)
    165         # defining the function inside the loop is not the best practice. However, since the number of iterations
    166         #( number of file are small), I put it insider the loop to improve the readibility of the code.

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    116                 else:
    117                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 118             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    119         return wrapper
    120     return _deprecate_kwarg

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
   4002         # else, only a single dtype is given
   4003         new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,
-> 4004                                      **kwargs)
   4005         return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   4006 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
   3460 
   3461     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
-> 3462         return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
   3463 
   3464     def convert(self, **kwargs):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
   3327 
   3328             kwargs['mgr'] = self
-> 3329             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
   3330             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
   3331 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    542     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None, **kwargs):
    543         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values,
--> 544                             **kwargs)
    545 
    546     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in _astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, klass, mgr, **kwargs)
    623 
    624                 # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
--> 625                 values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
    626                 values = values.reshape(self.shape)
    627 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy)
    701 
    702     if copy:
--> 703         return arr.astype(dtype)
    704     return arr.view(dtype)
    705 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

---

If I exclude column `PD_PRESSURE`, I don't receive any error.

I also tried `T['PD_PRESSURE'].dtype(float)` and I get the error but for other columns it works fine.

If I run `T[fields[0:-1]]=T[fields[0:-1]]` it works fine by itself, based on these I thought probably the error is coming from `PD_Pressure` column.

---

`T.info()` returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
DatetimeIndex: 3868696 entries, 2000-01-01 to 2017-04-11 
columns (total 6 columns): 
A object 
B object 
C object 
D object 
PD_PRESSURE object 
F object 
dtypes: object(6) 
memory usage: 1.0+ GB
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the actual error text?

Comment: @cwallenpoole I updated the question with the full error. Thanks

Comment: Please post `T.info()`. Also please explain how you know the error occurs when calling `astype` on the `PD_PRESSURE` column. It seems more likely to occur in a column that contains a sequence. For example, `pd.DataFrame({'A': [99, [1.23, 3.45]]})['A'].astype(float)` generates the ValueError you are seeing.

Comment: @unutbu this is `T.info()=<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 3868696 entries, 2000-01-01  to 2017-04-11 
columns (total 6 columns):
A                      object
B                      object
C                      object
D                      object
PD_PRESSURE     object
F                      object
dtypes:  object(6)
memory usage: 1.0+ GB'  column PD_PRESSURE is responsible for error because if i exclude column PD_PRESSURE, I wont receive any error  I also did `T['PD_PRESSURE'].dtype(float)` and I get the error but for other column it works fine.

Comment: @unutbu also if I run T[fields[0:-1]]=T[fields[0:-1]] it works fine by it self, based on these I thought probably the error is coming from PD_Pressure column.

Comment: Does `for col in fields[0: -1]: T[col] = pd.to_numeric(T[col], errors='coerce')` work?

Comment: @unutbu yes it worked, thank you so much for your help. so the issue was because of the inconsistent type of the column?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the problem was, since `dtypeCount` indicates the column contained only `None` and `float` values and I wasn't able to reproduce that error using only those kinds of values. However, `pd.to_numeric` seemed like a possible workaround since it has more robust error handling than `astype(float)`.

Comment: The "inconsistent type" of the column is handled by Pandas by giving the column a common `object` dtype. It's not necessarily a problem -- for example, `pd.DataFrame([None, 1.23], dtype='object').astype(float)` raises no error. A cell containing a sequence, however, would raise an error: `pd.DataFrame([None, [1.23, 3.14]]).astype(float)`.